# Nginx redirect string variable with wild card wordpress

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a bunch of this strange 404 error's in google search console and the URL's doesn't exists in my site and I need to redirect them to my homepage.

```
http://www.example.com/plugins/feedback.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fremain-url-1%2F&_fb_noscript=1
http://www.example.com/plugins/feedback.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fremain-url-2%2F&_fb_noscript=1
http://www.example.com/plugins/feedback.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fremain-url-3%2F&_fb_noscript=1
```

I've made this two attempts but it's not working

```
rewrite ^/plugins/feedback(/.*)$ http://www.example.com/ permanent;
rewrite ^/plugins/feedback.php?href=http://www.example.com(/.*)$ /blog/ permanent;
```

Is it possible to redirect this with one wild card?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect all `/plugins/feedback.php` or only ones with three specific `href` parameters?

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm trying to redirect all that contain specific href parameters. That's the reason why I need the wildcard. Ideally this should be: `rewrite ^/plugins/feedback.php(wild card here) /blog/ permanent;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive cannot be used to filter parameters because it uses a *normalized* URI which does not include the query string. You can access parameters using the `$args` variable, or individually using the `$arg_xxx` variables.

However, the `$request_uri` contains the entire URI (including query string) and could be used with an `if` block or `map` to test for the presence of the parameters you seek.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/some/regular/expression) {
    return 301 /;
}
```

The block could be placed in the `server` block scope, or within the location block which would normally process the `/plugins/feedback.php` URI.

See the following documents for details: [`if` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if), [`map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map), [`if` usage restrictions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: Great, this is useful. Thanks!